# Rest callout System.JSONException: Malformed JSON: Expected '[' at the beginning of List/Set

Tags: apex, visualforce, integration

```
{
    "msisdnList": [{
        "msisdn": "5409866259"
    }, {
        "msisdn": "5409866260"
    }, {
        "msisdn": "5409866265"
    }, {
        "msisdn": "5409866267"
    }, {
        "msisdn": "5409866299"
    }]
}


public class wrapMsisdnList {
        public String msisdn;
    }

public List<wrapMsisdnList> msisdnList {get;set;}
msisdnList = new List<wrapMsisdnList>();

Http http = new Http();
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
request.setEndpoint('https://demo9888763.mockable.io/getnumbers/');
request.setMethod('GET');
HttpResponse response = http.send(request);

if (response.getStatusCode() == 200 && response.getBody() != null) {
   
    msisdnList = (List<wrapMsisdnList>)json.deserialize(response.getbody(),List<wrapMsisdnList>.class);
    System.debug('results---->'+ msisdnList);      
           
}
```

What is the right way of reading the response "System.JSONException: Malformed JSON: Expected '[' at the beginning of List/Set "

```
(List<wrapMsisdnList>)json.deserialize(response.getbody(),List<wrapMsisdnList>.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a list:

```
{
    "msisdnList": [{
        "msisdn": "5409866259"
    }, {
        "msisdn": "5409866260"
    }, {
        "msisdn": "5409866265"
    }, {
        "msisdn": "5409866267"
    }, {
        "msisdn": "5409866299"
    }]
}
```

It's a JSON object with one top-level key, `msisdnList`, whose value is a list of objects that could be represented by your `wrapMsisdnList` class.

You'll need an outer wrapper class to represent this:

```
class OuterWrapper {
    List<wrapMsisdnList> msisdnList;
}
```

and deserialize to that class instead.